# Should c++23's "deducting this" feature be used with template function?

Tags: c++, c++23

I was reading https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/ specifically this piece

```
class cat {
    ...
    //After
    template <class Self>
    auto&& get_held_toy(this Self&& self) {
        return self.held_toy_;
    }

    //After + forwarding
    template <class Self>
    auto&& get_held_toy(this Self&& self) {
        return std::forward<Self>(self).held_toy_;
    }
};
```

I tried the following code, it still compiles. Is there any specific reason to use template function in Microsoft blog's example?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:25,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:25,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aclass+toy+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Aclass+cat+%7B%0A++++toy+held_toy_%3B%0A++public:%0A++++//After%0A++++template%3Cclass+Self%3E%0A++++auto%26%26+get_held_toy(this+Self%26%26+self)+%7B%0A++++++++return+self.held_toy_%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++//After+%2B+forwarding%0A++++auto%26%26+get_held_toy(this+cat%26%26+self)+%7B%0A++++++++return+std::forward%3Ccat%3E(self).held_toy_%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest+%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
// turn on c++23
class cat {
    ...
    //After + forwarding
    auto&& get_held_toy(this cat&& self) {
        return std::forward<Self>(self).held_toy_;
    }
};
```

Comment: It can't be a regular function because `self` will invariably have a different type for different arguments, and that will affect generated code -> that's literally a template.

Comment: Sufficient... to do what? This code exists for a purpose. You need to know what that purpose is.

Answer (score 4):

With this declaration:

```cpp
auto&& get_held_toy(this cat&& self) {
```

The explicit object parameter always has type `cat&&` (that is, an rvalue reference), so you could only call this function on rvalues:

```cpp
auto c = cat{};
// c.get_held_toy();  // error
std::move(c).get_held_toy();
cat{}.get_held_toy();
```

It's basically the same as:

```cpp
auto&& get_held_toy() && {
```

Which there is use for, but that isn't "deducing `this`" (it's just an explicit object parameter).

The real magic of:

```cpp
template <class Self>
auto&& get_held_toy(this Self&& self) {

// Or
auto&& get_held_toy(this auto&& self) {
```

Is that the type of the object parameter, what used to be "`*this`", can be deduced (hence "deducing `this`") from how it is being called:

```cpp
auto c = cat{};
toy_type& x = c.get_held_toy();  // mutable lvalue
const toy_type& y = std::as_const(c).get_held_toy();  // const lvalue
toy_type&& z = std::move(c).get_held_toy();  // xvalue
```

Without having to write 3 different overloads.

Answer (score 0):

First,  `this Self` allows to  determine the actual qualifier of object it was called for. One definition for all possible overloads without possiblity to cause ambigous declaration. For template function `&&` is a forwarding reference. If you remove template, you limit this function to xvalue\prvalue ones. It allows this type of recurrent behaviour:

```
class cat {
protected:
    ball held_toy_;
public:

    //After + forwarding
    template <class Self>
    auto&& get_held_toy(this Self&& self) {
        return std::forward<Self>(self).held_toy_;
    }
};

class displacer :  public cat
{
protected:
   player held_toy_;
   friend class cat;
};

int main()
{
    cat       mew;
    displacer boo;
    std::cout << typeid(mew.get_held_toy()).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(cat().get_held_toy()).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(boo.get_held_toy()).name() << std::endl; // displacer::held_toy_
}
```

Second, your way to define it is ill-formed in case of `std::forward<Self>(self).held_toy_;` - `Self` in not `cat` or `displacer`, substitution for `std::forward` fails.